# Getting "Segmentation Fault: core dumped when trying to write string to setter

Tags: c++, coredump

I have an dynamic array of objects that I resized. After resizing I can call the set methods for the int and double objects but not any of the setters with string objects. Anytime that I try to call the setter for the new index in the resized array I get a core dump.

This the main part of code that is generating the error.

```
void resizeAccounts(int newSize, Account *accounts, int acctNum, std::string fName,     :string lName, std::string acctP, double balance)
{       
Account* newArr = new Account[newSize];

for (int i=0; i<newSize-1; i++)
    newArr[i]=accounts[i];

delete [] accounts;
accounts = newArr;
accounts[newSize].setAccountNum(acctNum);
accounts[newSize].setFirstName(fName);
accounts[newSize].setLastName(lName);
accounts[newSize].setAccountPassword(acctP);
accounts[newSize].setBalance(balance);

for(int i=0; i<newSize; i++)
    std::cout << accounts[i].getAccountNum() << std::endl;
```

The setters I am using

```
void Account::setFirstName( std::string fName) 
{ firstName = fName; }
void Account::setLastName( std::string lName )
{ lastName = lName; }
void Account::setAccountPassword( std::string acctPass)
{ accountPassword = acctPass; }
void Account::setAccountNum( int acctNum)
{ accountNum = acctNum; }
void Account::setBalance( double bal)
{ balance = bal; }`
```

This is homework and I am not allowed to use vectors or most of the STL library.

Comment: Could you use `std::vector<Account>` and drop all that manual memory management?

Comment: Somewhat unrelated comment but you *really* want to pass strings into the setters by const reference instead of by value. It's good practise and avoids unnecessary additional copies.

Comment: What are the semantics of `resizeAccounts` supposed to be anyway? Why are you setting things on the new `accounts`? For example, if `newSize == oldSize`, presumably you don't want anything to change at all, do you?

Answer (score 5):

Array indexes run from `0` to `N - 1` so this:

```
accounts[newSize].setAccountNum(acctNum);
      //^^^^^^^^^
```

is accessing one past the end of the array, causing undefined behaviour. The valid indexes for `accounts` is therefore `0` to `newSize - 1`.

As `std::vector` is not permitted I won't mention it. At all.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have been staring at this for too long. It was the program trying to access the array outside of its bounds.

Answer (score 0):

C++ uses 0 based arrays.  This means that when you allocate an array of size `10` the first element is at index `0` and the last element is at index `9`.  In this case you're allocating an array of size `newSize` and then accessing the `newSize` element.  This is not a part of your array as the last element is `newSize - 1`.  This is why you are getting a crash.